# Kernel of the homomorphism $F\colon\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the evaluation function at $x= i$, the imaginary unit. I have shown that $F$ is a homomorphism, but to show that $\ker F= (x^2+1)\mathbb{R}[x]$ I am using some logical argument. It goes like this:

$\text{ker }F$ will contain only those $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ that contain $x^2+1$ as factor as $x=i\rightarrow x^2+1 = 0$. Again the functions in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ those had a factor of $x^2+1$ in them have already merged with the zero function of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Therefore, to regenerate those equivalent forms of zero functions we have to take the product $(x^2+1)\mathbb{R}[x]$. Therefore, $\text{ker }F= (x^2+1)\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Could you please enlighten me with a better way of proving it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ The kernel is a *principal* ideal, by $R[x]$ is Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID. $ $ But  if a nontrivial principal ideal contains an *irreducible* element $\,p\,$ then it is generated by $\,p\,$ (else the generator would be a *proper* divisor of $\,p).\,$ Thus the irreducible $\ x^2+1$ generates the kernel.

**Remark** $\ $ If you don't know about Euclidean domains or PIDs then you can see it more elementarily as follows. Note that the kernel is closed under gcd, since if $\,x=i\,$ is a root of $\,f,g\,$ then it is a root of $\,\gcd(f,g) = rf+sg\,$ (by Bezout). So if the kernel contains $g$ not divisible by $\,f = x^2+1,\,$ then it contains $\, \gcd(f,g),\,$ which is a *proper* factor of $\,f = x^2+1\,$ (since $\,f\nmid g).\,$ Thus we infer that $\,i\,$ is a root of a polynomial $\in \Bbb R[x]\,$ of degree $< 2 = \deg(f)$, contradiction.

[More generally,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140161/242) a nonzero ideal in a PID is generated by any nonzero element having the least number of prime factors.

Comment: Yes I got each of your POVs. Its always nice to see things from different angles.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure your first step is correct. Here is how this works :

1. You know that $(x^2+1) \in \ker(F)$.
2. If $f \in \ker(F)$, then by Euclidean division, you can write
   $$
   f(x) = q(x)(x^2+1) + r(x)
   $$
   where $\deg(r(x)) \leq 1$. Then
   $$
   0 = f(i) = 0 + r(i).
   $$
   Hence, $r(i) = 0$, but $r(x) = ax+b$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, which is only possible (why?) if $r(x) \equiv 0$. Hence,
   $$
   f \in (x^2+1).
   $$
   Hence, $\ker(F) = (x^2+1)$.

Comment: 1. what did you mean by first step ? Do mean the entire argument posted by me or any particular statement in that? 2. Yes I have understood it now.