# A variation of the argument to prove that $\{m/n:n \text{ is odd },n,m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, rational-numbers, principal-ideal-domains

I found [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~church/teaching/120-F15/math120-F15-hw7-solutions.pdf) which present a variation on how to prove that $R = \{m/n:n \text{ is odd and m/n is a reduced fraction},n,m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ with [respect to other posts in SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140150/show-that-the-ring-of-all-rational-numbers-which-when-written-in-simplest-form). I would like to ask you about the last step of the proof.

Basically they prove that $R$ is a integrity domain and they try to show that if we define $n = min \{p:p/q \in I, p,q > 0\}$ then $I = \langle n \rangle$. They first state that $n$ must be even and show that $\langle n \rangle \subseteq I$. To prove the converse they take $p/q \in I$ and distinguish cases where $n|p$ (no problem) and $n \nmid p$.

In this latter case they perform euclidean division $p = an + r$ and they state that by minimality, $a \ge 1,0 < r < n$. The conclusion reads $\frac{r}{q} =  \frac{p}{q} - \frac{a}{q} n \in I$ which contradicts the fact that $n$ is minimal.

**My problem**

I don't see very well why $a \ge 1$. Even in that situation I don't see why $a/q$ should be in $I$ so that $r/q$ is in $I$.

Can you help me to finish this argument?

Answer (score 1):

I wish to help you. I will prove that $R$ is a PID by using second way.

$R=\{\frac{m}{n}, m,n\in \mathbb Z, 2\nmid n  \}=\mathbb Z_{(2)} $ is the ring of fractions $\mathbb Z_S$ where $S=\mathbb Z-(2)$. Every ideal in $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ of the form $\{(2^n); n\in \mathbb N \}$