# Is $\mathbb{Z}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\Bigr]$ a Dedekind domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\mathbb{Z}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\Bigr]$ a Dedekind Domain? Can anyone help me with a detailed reasoning?

Comment: There are *many* definitions and/or characterizations of Dedekind domains. Which do you have available?

Comment: @Bill: Noetherian Integrally closed domain of Krull Dimension $1$. I am also familiar with the definition that every non zero ideal factors as prime ideals and every fractional ideal is invertible, though I don't consider myself handling these definitions very well:(

Comment: Hint: [it is a PID](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/137876/242) $\Rightarrow$ Dedekind.  Generally localizations preserves PIDs. $\ \ $

Comment: @Bill: You mean to say this: We know, that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a P.I.D, so localizing gives $\mathbb{Z}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\Bigr]$ as a P.I.D, and since it's a P.I.D its is a Dedikind domain.

Comment: That's one route.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is distilled from [Gone's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174510/is-mathbbz-bigl-frac12-frac13-bigr-a-dedekind-domain#comment401160_174510) and [rola's comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174510/is-mathbbz-bigl-frac12-frac13-bigr-a-dedekind-domain#comment401162_174510):

> By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137876/242), and since $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Z[\frac12,\frac13] \subset \Bbb Q = Q(\Bbb Z)$, we conclude $\Bbb Z[\frac12,\frac13]$ is a PID. PIDs are Dedekind, so we are done.
>
> (More generally, any localization of a PID is again a PID.)