# Subring of PID is also a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given a PID (Principal Ideal Domain), is every subring of PID also a PID ?

Do I have to show that every subring of a PID is an ideal ?

Comment: Any integral domain is a subring of its field of fractions, which is a PID. Therefore the three classes "subrings of fields", "subrings of PIDs" and "integral domains" are the same.

Comment: But we have this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137876/

Answer (score 17):

Answer: no. $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a PID, whereas $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/500254)