# Is any ideal of a PID again an ring (without unit) whose ideals are generated by one element (PID without $1$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I know that [a subring of a PID isn't necessarily a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001631/subring-of-pid-is-also-a-pid), but what about ideals?

Suppose $R$ is a PID, and $I$ is its ideal. Now take $J$ to be an ideal of $I$ (note that $J$ isn't necessarily an ideal of $R$), is $J$ necessarily generated by one element?

Sorry about the edit.

Comment: A *domain* is usually defined to have a unity.

Comment: Isn't a PID an unitary ring?

Comment: But $I$ is not even a ring as it does not necessarily contain a $1$. Even if you belong to the faction that allows rings without unity, then consider the following. If $I$ were a principal ideal of $I$ then we would need $I=Ia$ for some $a\in I$. This implies that $a=ia$ for some $i\in I$. This leads to the equation $a(1-i)=0$ in $R$. As $R$ is a domain we need either $a=0$ or $1=i\in I$. Neither alternative looks good :-)

Comment: Well, let us only consider the case when rings don't include $1$ whenever it doesn't have to......

Comment: Hmm. Above I equated "principal ideal" with "cyclic submodule". May be that's not how you define a principal ideal in a rng?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry, I forgot the $1$ is included in the definition of $PID$. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically $J$ will not be generated by one element as an ideal of $I$.  For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $I=(x)$, and $J=I$.  Then no element of $J$ generates it as an ideal of $I$.  Indeed, if $f(x)\in J$ has the form $$f(x)=ax^n+\text{terms with higher powers of $x$},$$ then every element of the ideal in $I$ generated by $f(x)$ will have a coefficient of $x^n$ that is an integer multiple of $a$.  Since not every rational number is an integer multiple of $a$, the ideal generated by $f(x)$ cannot be all of $J$.

Comment: Nice! My argument was losing its footing if we define *principal ideal generated by $x$* = *the smallest ideal containing the element $x$*, but yours works!