# Is this ring a PID? What are its invertible and irreducible elements?

Tags: ring-theory

> $R$ = $\left\{ {\left(\dfrac{a}{3^{n}}\right)|\; n \in N_{0}, a ∈ \mathbb{Z} }\right\}$. Is $R$ a PID? What are the invertible elements of $R$? What are the irreducible elements of $R$?

My thoughts: I think this is a PID, but I don't know how to begin proving this. I think the invertible elements are the elements such that $a=3^{m}$ for some $m ∈ N_{0}$?

Comment: Every ring between a PID $A$ and its quotient field is a PID, see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137876/a-subring-of-the-field-of-fractions-of-a-pid-is-a-pid-as-well).

Comment: Thank you, that link was very helpful. Do you have any thoughts about the irreducible elements in R?

Comment: Yes, what are your thoughts about the irreducible elements? You only thought about invertible elements.

Comment: I have considered both, but haven’t been able to come up with any irreducible elements. Sorry if this is a basic question but I’m struggling with fields of fractions - any point in the right direction would be appreciated