# Questions regarding subrings of $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, rational-numbers

Can the following cases happen?

1. A proper subring of $\Bbb Q$ with finitely many prime ideals
2. A proper subring of $\Bbb Q$ which is not a UFD

For case 1 I was thinking about some localisation of $\Bbb Z$ which would be a UFD and have unique prime = maximal ideal.

Comment: Your thoughts on #1 are good. For #2, note that every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ must contain $\mathbb{Z}$ (in a canonical way). You might try showing the more general fact: let $R$ be a PID, and let $F$ be its field of fractions. Then any subring of $F$ containing $R$ is also a PID. (I encourage you to try to do this yourself, but if you get stuck, the answers to following question provide solutions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137876/73817.)

Comment: In fact every subring will also be a ED right?

Comment: If $R$ is a Euclidean domain (e.g., if $R=\mathbb{Z}$, as in your case), then yes. The linked post shows that any subring between a PID $R$ and its field of fractions $F$ is a localization of $R$. Any (nonzero) localization of a Euclidean domain is again a Euclidean domain (though this is nonobvious!), which proves the claim.

Comment: So what is the final answer to my questions?
1. is possible 
2. is not

Comment: Yes, that's right. I would encourage you to write an answer to your own question to ensure that you understand the details of what is happening. (For instance: you should make precise what kind of localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ you are talking about in #1.)